# Pass all files from a branch to another

Tags: git, github, command-line

I have a git repository with two branches: master and master2. If I want to 
pass all existing files from master to master2, what command should i use? I tried whit this but it didn't work

```
git checkout master2
git checkout master files
git commit -m 'Add file files to master2.'
```

Comment: Isn't it simpler to do a merge from master into master2 ?

Comment: This is something you'd normally do with a merge. [What's your reason for wanting to do this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) There's probably a better way to solve your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have different options available:

Merge over the top:

```
git checkout master2
git merge master
```

Rebase underneath:

```
git checkout master2
git rebase master
```

Reset to an exact copy (including VCS history):

```
git checkout master2
git reset --hard master
```

Comment: tried but i have this error: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: @bero: Try adding `--allow-unrelated-histories` to the merge command.